# Child route getting called even after I navigate to parent route in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my angular application i have a parent route like this `''` and a child route like this `'child-route'`. Here is how my routes looks like

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: DefaultComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: FirstComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'child-route',
      component: AnotherComponent,
    },
    
];
```

Here is my components code

```
export class FirstComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log("parent");
  }
}

export class AnotherComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {

    console.log("child");
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

Now when i run `localhost:4200/child-route` in browser This is the result i am getting in console

`child parent child`

Why it is calling child again when it is navigated to parent route.

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://ng-run.com/edit/nmsFOC0WiT4ZRpFN4eGm?open=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) tries to navigate based on the current URL by default. See the "commands" parameter. So, I think you could instead call `this.router.navigate(['../'])` which acts similar to navigating up a directory. Or you can try passing in the parent as the "relativeTo" [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#navigationextras) argument. Which you can get off of an injected [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute):

`constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}`

`this.router.navigate([''], { relativeTo: route.parent })`

Comment: Tried both these ways but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Children path must be unique,
You should just give a path for FirstComponent,then your route work properly

Comment: I defined `home` as path for `FirstComponent`. Still getting same output.